# How to have a scoped toggle variable in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm coming from an AngularJS background where the ng-repeat has a scoped variables and I'm trying to figure out how to achieve a similar result without the need to create a new component which seems overkill for a lot of situations.

For example:

```
<div class="item" v-for="item in items">
  <div class="title">{{item.title}}</div>

  <a @click="showMore = !showMore">Show more</a>

  <div class="more" v-if="showMore">
    More stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

In AngularJS that code would work great, but in VueJS if you click on show more it causes the variable to update for every item in the items list, is there anyway to create a local scoped variable inside of the v-for `without the need to make a new component?`

I was able to get it to work by having the `showMore` variable be something like `@click="showMore = item.id"` and then `v-if="showMore.id = item.id"` but that also seems like too much extra complexity for something that should be much simpler? The other problem with that approach is you can only get one item to show more rather than allow for multiple items to be toggled shown at once.

I also tried changing the `items` model to include `item.showMore` but once again that adds more complexity and it causes a problem if you need to update an individual item since the model is changed.

Are there any simpler approaches to this?

Comment: But `showMore` is the responsibility of an individual item itself, and should not be delegated to the parent. I don't see why you want to avoid creating a component entirely, since this responsibility should lie within the scope of a single item.

Comment: @Terry Yes I agree the responsibility of that variable should lie within the scope of a single item, it's just a pain to create yet another new component for something so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/cincarnato/pen/VweQmey)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Items</h1>
      <div v-for="item in items" 
          :key="item.id" 
          class="item"
      >
        
        {{item.name}} 
        
        <button @click="show=item.id">
          Show More
        </button>
        
        <div v-if="item.id == show">
          {{item.desc}}
        </div>
        
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {id:1, name:"One", desc: "Details of One"},
        {id:2, name:"Two", desc: "Details of Two"},
        {id:3, name:"Three", desc: "Details of Three"}
      ],
      show: null
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
  .item{
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Only issue now is how to show multiple items at once